# How will the process tree of these fork() statements looks like?

Tags: c, linux, fork

ca anyone tell me what process tree will be generated by this c code?

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
   fork() || (fork() && fork());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with `man fork` and then a single `fork()`. Only after understanding it, proceed to more complex examples.

Answer (score 1):

Likely this is a homework. However, it is interesting.

First of all:

- `fork()` returns 0 for the child.
- `fork()` returns a value unequal to 0 for the parent.

Therefore in the server the first part of the logical or (`||`) unequals 0 and the rest of the expression is not executed on the parent: One call to fork.

In the child the first part is 0, so the rest `fork() && fork()` is executed. So on this child the first `fork()` returns a value unequal to zero causing to evaluate the second part. Therefore there are two new children. Both of them get a return value of 0, short-circuiting the evaluation.

Not tested, typed in Safari.